# Cannot deserialize the current JSON object C#

Tags: c#, json, .net

I have this JSON object which I want to deserialize

```
{
    "LoanInformationInqRs": {
        "MsgRsHdr": {
            "ResponseStatus": {
                "StatusDesc": "Success",
                "StatusCode": "I000000"
            }
        },
        "Body": {
            "LoanInformationList": {
                "LoanInformation": [
                    {
                        "LoanAmount": "0",
                        "PaidAmount": "0",
                        "RemainingAmount": "0",
                        "TotalDueAmount": "0"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried

```
public class LoanInfoDto
    {
        public LoanInformationInqRs LoanInformationInqRs { get; set; }
    }

public class LoanInformationInqRs
    {
        public MsgRsHdr MsgRsHdr { get; set; }
        public Body Body { get; set; }
    }

public class Body
    {
        public List<LoanInfo> LoanInformationList { get; set; }
    }

public class LoanInfo
    {
       
        public string TotalLateInstallments { get; set; }
        public string PaidAmount { get; set; }
        public string RemainingAmount { get; set; }
        public string TotalDueAmount { get; set; }


    }
```

---

```
    string res = httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    LoanInfoDto response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LoanInfoDto>(res);
```

I got this error

```
{
  "Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {\"name\":\"value\"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Entities.LoanInfo]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.\r\nTo fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List<T>) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.\r\nPath 'LoanInformationInqRs.Body.LoanInformationList.LoanInformation', line 1, position 152."
}
```

Comment: Paste your JSON into https://QuickType.io - it will generate C# for you that Just Works. Other similar services exist (json2csharp for example) that do a similar thing. Generating c# from json is one of those boring boilerplate jobs that we shouldn't even be paining the most junior apprentice with ; devolve it to a computer. By the way if this json is coming from an api that publishes an openapi/swagger, feed the swagger spec into nswag/autorest for even more autonomization

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is with your `Body` class, the correct class will be like this.

because the `body` node does not contain an array but a single object.

```
public class ResponseStatus
{
    public string StatusDesc { get; set; }
    public string StatusCode { get; set; }
}

public class MsgRsHdr
{
    public ResponseStatus ResponseStatus { get; set; }
}

public class LoanInformation
{
    public string LoanAmount { get; set; }
    public string PaidAmount { get; set; }
    public string RemainingAmount { get; set; }
    public string TotalDueAmount { get; set; }
}

public class LoanInformationList
{
    public List<LoanInformation> LoanInformation { get; set; }
}

public class Body
{
    public LoanInformationList LoanInformationList { get; set; }
}

public class LoanInformationInqRs
{
    public MsgRsHdr MsgRsHdr { get; set; }
    public Body Body { get; set; }
}

public class LoanInfoDto
{
    public LoanInformationInqRs LoanInformationInqRs { get; set; }
}
```

I would suggest you use [json2csharp](https://json2csharp.com/) converting tool to help you to get those classes

Comment: I would suggest a Visual Studio built-in feature named "Paste JSON as classes" instead third party tools. It is faster.